# Amazon Managed Apache Airflow: Can MWAA pull a docker image from AWS ECR?

Tags: amazon-ecr, mwaa

We are looking into using MWAA and we already have docker images stored in ECR.

Is it possible to pull a docker image in ECR from a DAG running in MWAA ?

Comment: were you able to do it ? Would love to know the procedure.

Comment: unfortunately, the team decided not to use airflow. Had to shelf this. Would love to have used it though.

Comment: @wi3o What did you use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. `DockerOperator` takes the `image` parameter, this can be an ECR URL.

You will have to ensure that your Airflow has access to the ECR. For `DockerOperator` this can be done by configuring an Airflow connection like `docker_conn_id`.